# Painting JSON data schema

Tags: json, standards, jsonschema

I'm writing the documentation for my project.
I need to represent the JSON nested schema, but I don't want include the raw-code.

Is there a standard way to represent JSON data schema as graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a standard way, and I doubt it will ever exist. Due to its graph nature, you might leverage any representation of graphs.

For json-schema you might have a look to any of the following libraries: [matic](https://github.com/mattyod/matic), [docson](https://github.com/lbovet/docson) or [jsonary](http://jsonary.com/).